# How to read selected values and refresh token in profileservice of Identity Server4 to generate custom claims in newly generated token?

Tags: identityserver4

#Identity Server4.

Below is the scenario:

User access MVC client app, it redirect to identity server4(ID4). User input uerid and password ID4 validate and return the access token. It show the MVC home page.

On MVC homepage user select Role and Organization-Unit (its business requirement).
User will submit or enter two values in textbox on homepage 1) refresh token 2) selected Role and Organization-Unit. After click on "Submit" button, below are my query or i get stuck.

1. how to pass the selected value Role and Organization-Unit, with Refresh Token to ID4.
2. How to read those values in profileservice of ID4.

So that newly generated token should have, selected "Role and Organization-Unit" as custom claim or claims.

Can you some guide me or help on this with actual code snippet.

expectation is newly generated token should have, selected "Role and Organization-Unit" as custom claim or claims. Can you some guide me or help on this with actual code snippet.